# How to format json data for PowerBI (Error: "Additional characters were found at the end of the JSON entry.")

Tags: json, azure, powerbi, azure-blob-storage, dataformat

I am sending data from Node-RED to the Azure Blob Storage and use the Storage Account as a Data Source for Power BI. The messages that arrive to Node-RED are being saved in a json file (every day), which will be uploaded to the cloud at the end of the day. I have a problem with the format of these messages because I get this error when I try to edit the data in Power BI:

```
Details: "Additional characters were found at the end of the JSON entry."
```

Unfortunately I am inexperienced in this topic and don't know how to fix it. 
These are the messages in my file:

```
{"timestamp": "2019-05-11T22:39:13.908347", "current_ma": 22, "voltage_mv": 229979, "energy_wh": 15, "power_mw": 0}
{"timestamp": "2019-05-11T22:39:18.843627", "current_ma": 22, "voltage_mv": 230069, "energy_wh": 15, "power_mw": 0}
{"timestamp": "2019-05-11T22:39:23.935679", "current_ma": 22, "voltage_mv": 229988, "energy_wh": 15, "power_mw": 0}
{"timestamp": "2019-05-11T22:39:28.865907", "current_ma": 21, "voltage_mv": 230048, "energy_wh": 15, "power_mw": 0}
{"timestamp": "2019-05-11T22:39:33.810613", "current_ma": 21, "voltage_mv": 230081, "energy_wh": 15, "power_mw": 0}
```

I used to have each one of these messages in one file but it was taking too much space, so I am guessing the problem has something to do with joining all the messages in one file. Maybe the separation between them?

Answer (score 0):

I assume issue may be resolved: There is a similar thread discussion https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-format-json-data-for-PowerBI-Error-Additional-characters/m-p/689642#M23195

If the issue still persist, I would request, Please feel to contact us again